# In the neo4j sandbox, how to display nodes with the same label close to each other?

Tags: neo4j

For example, the label of some nodes is 'A', and the label of other nodes is 'B'. In the sandbox, the colors of the two group of nodes are different, but they are mixed together when displayed. I want nodes with the same label to be close to each other. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking for a custom layout.

The neo4j browser uses automated layout based on relationships (part of d3.js).  The only way you can get what you want in the sandbox (to my knowledge) is to manually click on the nodes and drag them around.  Note, this arrangement is only for your current session, it isn't saved.

To do what you want programmatically you'd need to implement a custom viewer, or see if one of the available tools has a layout that would meet your needs.

Cytoscape, and Gephi are two that I use with Neo4j.  I wouldn't call them easy to use, and I don't recall any layout that does exactly what you want (though a few do something similar, in that they can layout by properties/labels)